# How can I attach to layout some ViewData without doing it in every controller's method?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have custom role system in my webapp, but I'd want to hide some things on website

In current approach I'm sending something like this to View:

```
@If(ViewData["isAbleTo___"].ToString() == true.ToString())
{
    <div>secret</div>
}
```

But I'd want to avoid doing it for every

- isAbleToA
- isAbleToB
- isAbleToC
- isAbleToD

in every controller's method for every controller

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected Context _dbcontext;

    public ControllerBase()
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        ViewData[""] = _dbcontext.....
    }
}

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    public HomeController(Context dbcontext)
    {
        _dbcontext = dbcontext
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong approach to begin with. Permissions should be handled via [roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.1) or [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1). For example, instead of setting a key in `ViewData` to say that the user can do A, the user should be assigned to a role like `CanA`. Then you can simply check `User.IsInRole('CanA')` instead.

Or if you need more logic involved in making the decision, you can create a policy handler and then [check if the user passes that policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

...

@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "CanA")).Succeeded)
{
    // Show `A` stuff
}
```